# Unable to update the Oracle DB with JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Unable to update the table named `equipment_management`.

The SQL Query is not a problem as the query executes perfectly in my Oracle SQL Developer

Then realized that commit could be the problem but the problem existed even after the commit.

Below is the simple code which I'm using.

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);

String sql = "update equipment_management set status='Processed' where equipmentid='FER'";

System.out.println(sql);

statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

int i=statement.executeUpdate();

if(i==1)
System.out.print("Data Inserted");

else
System.out.print("Data not Inserted");

con.commit();
```

The data type of columns in equipment_management is `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)`. The problem mainly lies in `statement.executeUpdate();` where when attempted to updated the table `equipment_management`, the code exits abruptly without any error message.

Then on giving hope, realized that I had introduced a new column in this table and after this only I'm not able to perform any update of table data with JDBC.

On Introducing a new column, not able to update the table. Is it related to Oracle Developer tool or with JDBC or my simple piece of code.

Comment: 'the code exits abruptly without any error message' what error u receive ?

Comment: Without any error message? Please, show us your exceptions menagement.

Comment: @mauretto: try{-my code shown above- }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }finally {
   con.close();
   statement.close();
  }

Comment: Try to close statement before con and try to print something as first statement in both catch and finally blocks to ensure the exception been thrown.

Comment: Post the create table statement for `equipment_management`.